# only native call stack shown

Tags: c#, crash, stack-overflow, crash-dumps

My .NET application is crashing. Upon generating full crash dump using Debug Diag, dump file is created named after 'stackoverflow' and i guess there is a stack overflow exception with some thread.
Doing crash dump analysis using Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate, it shows only the native call stack and no .NET/Managed call stack making it difficult to figure out what's wrong with my application.
This is what i see:

```
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd = {System.IntPtr}, int msg = 0, System.IntPtr wparam = {System.IntPtr}, System.IntPtr lparam = {System.IntPtr})  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 13, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 13, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 13, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 13, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 13, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 13, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})  Unknown
```

Comment: I said it shows only the native stack, i need to know which part of the application caused. What indicates it's because of Text property? How can i figure it out which control?

Comment: Which button did you press for debugging? There is "native only" and "mixed"

Comment: I used Mixed Mode